# How do I stop emacs from highlighting the line under the mouse in shell

Tags: shell, emacs

In emacs shell, invoked using `M-x shell`, input lines under the cursor are highlighted, so you can then "mouse 2: insert after prompt as new input" to repeat the command. I'd prefer not to have this activated and just select text under the mouse as I do in a regular terminal and middle click to insert (I know I can do this in emacs but I don't get any visual feedback until I stop the mouse selection).

Is there any way to do this? I've done quite a bit of searching and can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message comes from [this function in comint.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/comint.el#L1839).

Setting `comint-use-prompt-regexp` to a non-nil value should do what you want.

A good solution would probably be something like this (put the following somewhere in your initialization; regexp taken from `comint-prompt-regexp` docstring):

```lisp
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'comint-use-prompt-regexp) t)
            (set (make-local-variable 'comint-prompt-regexp) "^[^#$%>\n]*[#$%>] *")))
```

Comment: perfect; of course I shouldn't be using the mouse at all in emacs, but until that time, this will do very nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify the version of Emacs and I do not see that behaviour in my Emacs why I type M-x shell. However, a little googling turned up this:

```
(setq comint-highlight-input nil)
```

which is something that you can set in ~/.emacs.

This variable does not exist in GNU Emacs 25, even though there is a reference to a specific face (highlighting) to use in that case. Either that is a mere reminisence from when the feature was available or it is something that is actually enabled with another package. You can test by starting emacs with the "-Q" option and start shell as the first thing, if the behaviour does not appear, it is something that is related to your startup configuration or something you do before starting the shell.

The post in which the above variable was mentioned can be seen here:

```
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2002-August/001134.html
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, though -- or at least it didn't for me (emacs 24.4).`comint-highlight-input` is the font face with which to highlight shell input, but the message on mouseover comes from the `mouse-face` property, which is added only if `comint-use-prompt-regexp` is nil.

Comment: thankyou; this didn't work for me, however. I'm on emacs 24.3.1.